# Website downloaded two times after each failure

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some Python code which scrapes data from a UNESCO website. It runs well enough, but if there are errors fetching any of the pages, then the function which grabs the data is called again, and the page is grabbed. Unfortunately, the page is grabbed twice, and I don't know why.

The full code is available [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30099/why-do-failures-get-reprocessed-twice). But the function which is causing issues is as follows:

```
country_code_list = [["AFG"],["ALA"],["DZA"],["ALB"]]
countries = {"AFG":"Afghanistan","ALA":"Aland Islands","ALB":"Albania","DZA":"Algeria"}
base_url = "http://www.unesco.org/xtrans/bsresult.aspx?lg=0&c="

def get_page(self, url, country, all_books, thread_no, sleep_time=0):
    time.sleep(sleep_time)

    try: 
        target_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        if sleep_time != 0:
            print("Thread {0} successfully fetched {1}"\
                  .format(self.thread_no, url))
    except Exception, error:
        print("Thread {0} Error getting {1} while processing {2}: ".format\
              (thread_no, url, country), error)
        self.get_page(url, country, all_books, thread_no, (sleep_time + 1))

    page = BeautifulSoup(target_page, parse_only=only_restable)
    books = page.find_all('td',class_="res2")
    for book in books:
        all_books.append(Book (book,country))
    page.decompose()    

    for title in all_books:
        title.export(country)
```

The only other code that interacts with that function is the code which iterates across the web page, that code is here but I don't think it's the problem:

```
    def build_list(self, code_list, countries, thread):
    '''  Build the list of all the books, and return a list of Book objects
    in case you want to do something with them in something else, ever.'''
    for country in code_list:

        print('Thread {0} now processing {1} \n'.format(self.thread_no, \
                                                        countries[country]))
        results_total = self.get_total_results(country, base_url)

        with open(count_file, "a") as count_table: 
            print(country + ": " + str(results_total), file=count_table)

        for page_num in range(0,results_total,10):
            all_books = []
            url = base_url + country + "&fr=" + str(page_num)
            try: 
                self.get_page(url, country, all_books, self.thread_no)
            except Exception, error:
                print("Thread {0} Error getting {1} while processing {2}: "\
                      .format(self.thread_no, url, country), error)
                self.get_page(url, country, all_books, self.thread_no, 1)
    print("Thread {0} completed.".format(self.thread_no))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your exception code, add a `return` statement:

```
except Exception, error:
    print("Thread {0} Error getting {1} while processing {2}: ".format\
          (thread_no, url, country), error)
    self.get_page(url, country, all_books, thread_no, (sleep_time + 1))
    return
```

Otherwise, it will continue processing the failed page.

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. Thanks, will update and test.

Comment: You may want to add some code to prevent an infinite loop.  If the exception happens over and over, your code will get stuck unless you add something like: `if sleep_time > 10: break`